# How do I accept an answer or start a bounty for a question?

Tags: discussion

I have asked several questions on Blender Stack Exchange and just noticed this comment on a few of them, "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?"

My answer is no to both because I don't know how to do that.  I would like to be more familiar with the procedures here.  I am proceeding with brute force through Blender, using BlenderBasics_4thEdition2011.pdf and as I learn as well as teach a class that includes beginning and advanced students I am coming across many things I don't understand.

Blender is an interesting puzzle.  I am enjoying the ride but I think that along with learning it I should also try to understand the etiquette of the Stack Exchange.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: just take a look at the help in this site and you'll find the answers , and questions of this kind should be asked in the meta

Comment: This must be placed in Meta not in the main site.

Comment: All being said, awarding bonuses to get answers isn't necessary. Unless your problem is an obscure/localized one that you want people to spend more than a few minutes on just try to word your question as clearly as possible. See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/608/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-is-hard-to-describe?cb=1

Answer (score 6):

**Accepting answers:**
You accept and answer by clicking on the "nike"-icon to the left of the answer. It then turns green. You can only do this with one answer pr. question.

**Bounty:**
Bounties can be started two days after question was posted. They are a way to offer your own rep to attract more answers, since users will put more effort in for a large reward.

Answer (score 4):

Naioai Studios appears to have already addressed the *How*, so I'll just add some clarification and some of the common etiquette here on Blender.SE.

First, accepting an answer. It is customary to accept the **most helpful answer**, as soon as possible (be sure to give a reasonable amount of time for other answers to be posted if it does not solve your question exactly). You can un-accept an answer and accept another at any time, just click the check-mark again, and click another one. Up-voting the accepted answer is also common etiquette, as if it solves your question it deserves the up-votes. **Stack-Exchange sites are *heavily* reliant on active voting by all members** to sort good questions/answers from the bad ones.

[image: Accept Answer]

---

Now for Bounties. A question becomes eligible for a bounty after **two days** from initial posting, with **no accepted answers**. If a question becomes eligible, you can start a bounty by clicking the little text underneath the question that says `start a bounty`.

[image: start a bounty]

You can start a bounty on any question, regardless of if it is your own or not, same for all users. Notice though that the minimum amount is **50 rep**, so you need to have enough reputation in order to start one.

Comment: Please use screenshots that show the site *as is*.

Comment: Usually I don't accept an answer unless it solves the problem, or shows that what I am looking for is definitely not possible.  So if it is helpful but doesn't actually solve the problem, I usually just upvote it in case someone in the future comes along with a full solution.  And as an aside, where did those screenshots come from?